# How to call SOAP WS from Oracle DB 11.2 with payload more than 32000 chars?

Tags: oracle, plsql, soap

I need to call SOAP web service from Oracle DB where a payload consists of a file in base64 encoding.

The problem is that I have limitations in payload size — 32 000 chars (`varchar` type). Examples, [here](https://technology.amis.nl/2008/06/16/rapid-plsql-web-service-client-development-using-soapui-and-utl_http/) and [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2389756). So it means that I cannot call a web service where the payload is quite huge.

How do I make a payload increase the limitation of `varchar2` type.

Comment: I've never used `utl_http` but it looks similar to `utl_smtp` that is used to send email. I guess to break the `varchar2` limit you have to have your payload as `clob` and then split the payload in chuncks accepted by `utl_http.write_text` and call `write_text` for each chunck.

Comment: Thank you for idea: http://www.kurzhals.info/2012/03/using-chunked-transfer-with-plsql-utl_http-write_text.html

Answer (score 0):

To go over the 32k characters limitation, you can try to use a `CLOB` with `utl_http`. Here is a procedure to do it :

```
PROCEDURE write_clob_to_http_request(pc_clob IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB)
IS
    ln_offset      NUMBER := 1;
    ln_i           NUMBER := 1;
    ln_amount      NUMBER := 32767;
    ln_clob_length NUMBER := dbms_lob.getlength(pc_clob);
    lv_buffer      VARCHAR2(32767);

    luh_http_request utl_http.req;
BEGIN

    luh_http_request := utl_http.begin_request('http://SoapServiceLocation' , 'POST', 'HTTP/1.1');
    utl_http.set_header(luh_http_request, 'Content-Type', lv_http_content_type);
    utl_http.set_header(luh_http_request, 'Content-Length', LENGTH(pc_content));
    utl_http.set_header(luh_http_request, 'SOAPAction', 'http://SoapServiceLocation');

    IF dbms_lob.isopen(pc_clob) != 1 THEN
        dbms_lob.open(pc_clob, 0);
    END IF;

    WHILE ( ln_offset < ln_clob_length )
    LOOP
        dbms_lob.read(pc_clob, ln_amount, ln_offset, lv_buffer);
        UTL_HTTP.write_text(luh_http_request, lv_buffer);
        ln_offset := ln_offset + ln_amount;
        ln_i := ln_i + 1;
    END LOOP; 

    IF dbms_lob.isopen(pc_clob) = 1 THEN
        dbms_lob.close(pc_clob);
    END IF;

    luh_http_response := utl_http.get_response(luh_http_request);
    utl_http.read_text(luh_http_response, pc_content);
    utl_http.end_response(luh_http_response);
END write_clob_to_http_request;
```

You can easily create a `CLOB` by concatenating `VARCHAR2` variables:

```
pc_content CLOB := TO_CLOB('a string') || TO_CLOB('another string)...;
```